# Auth::user() relationship return null laravel 5.3

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5.3, relationship

I have the following code in my `App\User` model.

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'username','dob','name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token','created_at','updated_at',
    ];

    protected $dates =[
        'dob',
    ];

    public function roleuser(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Role');
    }
}
```

class CreateRolesTable extends Migration
{

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('rolename');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}


public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('roles');
}
```

}

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned()->default(2);
        $table->string('username',32);
        $table->date('dob');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}


public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('users');
}
```

}

i'm using 1 to 1 relationship between user and role.

Calling `{{ Auth::user()->roleuser }}` from a Blade template returns null but I am expecting a `App\Role` instance.

Can someone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: What does your database schema look like?

Comment: Can you update your answer with that? It is very hard to read that code all condensed as a comment. Also does the role_id value for the user in your database match a role in the roles table?

Comment: its done, hope u can solve my prob. thx

Comment: The way code formatting works on this site, is you have to indent by 4 characters so it can distinguish code from the rest of the text. That's why the first and last part of your code are not formatted, you need to indent everything an additional 4 spaces.

Comment: sounds like the relationship doesn't exist in the db, if the relationship is setup correctly that is.

Comment: @lagbox. i set the relationship from the model right?

Comment: @lagbox  when i access $user in view it returns the value, but when i access $user->roleuser it returns null

Comment: which means, the relationship isn't setup right, or the relationship doesn't exist in the DB.   in your case the relationship is setup wrong, you aren't specifying the key on that relationship, eloquent is going to look for a key named  `roleuser_id` since that is the name of that relationship method.    This relationship should be called `role`, not sure why its named anything else, since you have to override convention everywhere now to deal with this odd naming of keys and relationships.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using 1 to 1 relationship between user and role.

If you're using a one to one relationship, you should use the [`hasOne` method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) that way it will return an instance of the model and not a collection which I think is what you're getting now (not null) like you thought.

Comment: where should i put that method?  in user model or role model?

Comment: It replaces where you used the `belongsTo` method.

Comment: now i got this error....SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'roles.user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `roles` where `roles`.`user_id` = 1 and `roles`.`user_id` is not null limit 1) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\latihan\resources\views\Posts\index.blade.php)

Comment: My bad actually what you had before is correct, but do you have data in the database with the correct IDs?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/KNoiA https://imgur.com/M0GRmTr. take a look at that

Comment: when i access $user in view it returns the value, but when i access $user->roleuser it returns null

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the key used for the relationship. You are not passing any additional paremeters to the relationship method to override the naming conventions. By default it looks for very particular named fields. It is going to look for `roleusers_id` because you named the method `roleusers` instead of the more normal `role` name. If you named it `role` it would look for the `role_id` field by default. You will need to override the key used if you keep it named `roleusers`.  [The docs mention this directly]

[Laravel 5.3 Docs - Eloquent - Relationships - One to Many (Inverse)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse)